# What exactly use of dealloc method in Objective c? when it will call?

Tags: objective-c

My Question is When the dealloc method will cal before the application termination, If it happens , When the application terminates all the memory of the objects and application will be removed from memory, then what is the use of writing dealloc method?

Answer (score 0):

This is a general question about memory management. You use dealloc in Objective-C, free in C etc. to clean the memory allocated for the variables that are no longer in use. When the application terminates of course all of the memory allocated by the application will be released. However, if your application keeps allocating memory as it runs, and if the user runs the application for long enough, unless you release unused memory, the device's memory would get eventually used up. This is why you need to use dealloc.

The dealloc method describes how the object will be released. When an object is being deallocated unless you override the dealloc method only the object's pointer will be released. Therefore, in order to release properties and fields in your object you need to manually release them in your dealloc method.